# jquery success function removing div

Tags: jquery, html

My task is to get the html data from an ajax call  and upon success i want bind to a specific  tag and remove the rest of html data.

"Specific div tag here in this case is #divtest

i wanted to remove are divtbldataresults ,divend

data is html  "

THE ISSUE IS IT IS THROWING JAVASCRIPT ERROR, I WAS WONDERING DOES MY CODE HAVE SYNTAXT ISSUES OR AM I DOING SOMETHING WRONG .THANKS IN ADVANCE

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   cache: false,
   url: '@Url.Content("~/SyndromicQuery/QueryPeriod")',
   data: { selectedItem: selectedItem,
   startdate: startdate,
   enddate: enddate,
   queryid: queryid
},
success: function (data) {
   var jqObj = $(data);
   jqObj.find('divtbldataresults').remove();
   jqObj.find('divend').remove();
   $('canvas').remove();
   $("#divtest").empty().append(jqObj);
```

}

Comment: You did close it right? `});`

Comment: I think you are missing the class (.) or the id (#) marker in the selector. Also, if this divs are a first level childs you need to use .filter() instead of .find()

Comment: Have you closed the brackets for the success function and `ajax()` in your full code or are they really missing?

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <html>
<head>
   
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/theme/jquery.ui.all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Chart.js"></script>      
</head>

Comment: The above error is happening when i use var jqObj = $(data);

Answer (score 0):

This could be because `#divtest` is a child of one of the page elements you are removing.

Comment: The error is coming once i put the html data into jquery object. var jqObj = $(data)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're looking for: `<divtbldataresults>` or `<divend>` wich I hope you are not using!

If they are classes, try:

```
var jqObj = $(data);
   jqObj.find('.divtbldataresults').remove();
   jqObj.find('.divend').remove();
```

If they are id's, try:

```
var jqObj = $(data);
       jqObj.find('#divtbldataresults').remove();
       jqObj.find('#divend').remove();
```

Also, if they're first level (or direct) childs. try:

```
var jqObj = $(data);
       jqObj.filter('.divtbldataresults').remove();
       jqObj.filter('.divend').remove();
```

Comment: I have tried evrything still the error throws the error come when i use this statement var jqObj = $(data)

Comment: maybe you should post what data returns (before that) just console.log(data) and paste it here

Comment: Toni it is working fine now as i converted html to var jqObj = $.parseHTML(data)

Comment: I am glad you solved the problem. but there is no way your original code worked, right? you needed to add the class/id identifier, no?